# What is the opposite of interorganization?

Tags: vocabulary

What is the opposite of *interorganization*? Is it even a correct word?

*Interorganization* means the things that happen inside the organization (I think). What about the things that happen outside of the organization?

Answer (score 4):

The prefix *inter-* usually indicates interaction between two or more entities, so inter-organizational would be some process that takes places between several organizations.

The usual "opposite" of that would be *intra-*, meaning a process that happens *within* an entity. So an *internal* process inside an organization would be intra-organizational.

Compare to *internet* versus *intranet*.

For things that are inside or outside one single organization, I would suggest using *internal* and *external*.

Answer (score 3):

`inter-` means *between* or *involving two or more different things, places, people, etc*. The antonym prefix for it is `intra-` which means *inside, into, within*:

*intra-departmental*: within a department.

Comment: Aw! Two answers already there before I finished typing my answer! :D

Answer (score 2):

You may use [extra-organisational](http://blog.thylmann.net/2005/01/12/extra-organizational-knowledge-processes/) :

> Companies might also want external knowledge, to get new ideas or just because it is cheaper or because they just don’t have it internally.

Source: http:http://blog.thylmann.net/2005/01/12/extra-organizational-knowledge-processes/

Answer (score 0):

**Interorganizational (Adjective)** means things related to systems,relationships, etc. **between two or more different organizations**.

So the best possible opposite to it would be **Intraorganizational** which means Inside the same Organization.

And i find not the word Interorganization.